# modal popup and parent frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a modal dialog box is open in iFrame, intially I can't focus a textbox in parent frame. The text box gets focused/selected and the looses focus right away. When I click (right or left click) on the content of modal dialog box, then I can select/focus the text box in parent frame. The same thing happens with drop down menu, it closes right away.

I've tried jquery trigger and parent.foucs but neither worked, is there something similar I can do programmatically?

I'm using dojo framework but I'm thinking its more of a html issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is this an `alert` dialogue, or something custom?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. Had to set autofocus="false" for dialog setup. It's a framework specific solution.